# Call a javascript function from another file

Tags: jquery, javascript

In wordpress, to use $ instead of jQuery prefix, i added the following code around all js code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    ...
});
```

It works well, but i cannot call an object from another javascript file, the following problem persists:

```
Slider is not defined
```

This is my code:

**file1.js**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var slider = new Slider();
});
```

**file2.js**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function Slider() {
       this.nb_ele = 10;
    }
});
```

It seems that because the workspace of two js files is different so they can't call function from another one. Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have is that `Slider` is not accessible outside of its scope as that's defined by the `.ready()` though you've used shorthand for that.  The function needs to be available in the global scope:

file1.js

```
function Slider() {
   this.nb_ele = 10;
}

jQuery(function($) {
  // ...
});
```

file2.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var slider = new Slider();
});
```

If you want Slider to stay in the document ready, you'll need to use a function expression to add the function to the global object:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    window.Slider= function () {
       this.nb_ele = 10;
    };
});
```

See Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449435/splitting-up-jquery-functions-across-files

Comment: That's what i need, thank you. I need to use the jQuery in Slider function so it must stay in the jQuery scope but by adding "window" before the function name, it'll be added to the global object.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same kind of problem.

You can also solve it with:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){

your code in here

});
```

You need also to use that trick in all of your javascript files, i mean `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();`.

After that **Dammeul** is right.